# cmd action when program return status

Tags: batch-file, cmd, usb, relay

I have USB relay and i can control it by cmd file ON.cmd and OFF.cmd. I want to create TOOGLE.cmd file. 
I can check relay status by sending `hidusb-relay-cmd id=YWM8T STATUS` and its return `State: R1=OFF R2=OFF`. How to send `hidusb-relay-cmd id=YWM8T ON ALL` if `State: R1=OFF R2=OFF` and send `hidusb-relay-cmd id=YWM8T OFF ALL` if `State: R1=ON R2=ON`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
cd %tmp%
hidusb-relay-cmd id=YWM8T STATUS|findstr "OFF">sh.tmp
set "out="
set /P out=<sh.tmp
del /q /f sh.tmp
if defined out goto :def
hidusb-relay-cmd id=YWM8T OFF ALL
goto :exit
:def
hidusb-relay-cmd id=YWM8T ON ALL
:exit
```

How it works:

1. It looks for `OFF` in the output of the `hideusb-relay-cmd` command and redirects it to a temporary file.
2. It resets the `out` variable (if you're gonna use this on the commandline, it's quite necessary).
3. It sets `out` to the contents of the temporary file.
4. It deletes the temporary file.
5. It checks if `out` has any value. If it has, `goto :def` and skip the `hidusb-relay-cmd id=YWM8T OFF ALL` command. If it doesn't, it doesn't skip it.
6. Wherever it went it exits afterwards.

Comment: No problem, @AlexIschenko